# How can I remove this bathroom light cover?

Tags: bathroom, light

I tried opening the cover use a coin/ screwdriver with no luck. Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Does it turn?  Maybe it needs to line up.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

Comment: It was turning on until midday and then stopped turning on.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right. Just find a better fitting tool. It should nearly fill the cavity. Press firmly so you don't booger things up worse and twist. The attachment is similar to a peanut can lid--just a lip in a groove.

You may also be able to slip a thinner tool in from an upward angle and pry downward.

Comment: Thanks.  will try with a better fitting tool as I don't want to worsen it up.